# VSCode server extension installs itself on host instead on the CT

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm trying to set up a remote development using VSCode and its remote extension but I've got a problem. The extension install itself on the Proxmox host instead on the Container indicated in config file.

The extension connects perfectly to the Container and it work like a charm. On the host, I've got the firewall with the port forwarding enabled (I use just 1 public IP, 1 domain name per Container, and 1 SSH different port per Container). It forwards the port 22200 to the port 22 of the Container.

*.ssh/config*

```
Host container.domain.it
    HostName container.domain.it
    User root
    Port 22200
    PasswordAuthentication Yes
```

**I noticed this because Proxmox couldn't start the Containers anymore. It threw several errors. Taking a look at all active processes on the host I noticed several VSCode processes.** Stopping the extension and closing VSCode, all processes on the Proxmox host went terminated and Proxmox works again perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem laid in Proxmox itself. I had to edit */etc/sysctl.conf* on the host and increase these limits to:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 256
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 16384
```